# All ports are open but can not curl from textfiles

Tags: curl, ssh

I am a newbie.
Trying to curl from this site.
The error I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PikSm.png)

All my ports are open, what could be the issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY0mQ.png)

Comment: It seems like your vagrant server cannot reach textfiles.com. From vagrant, do `ping -c5 textart.com`. Do you get a ping response? If you don't, try `traceroute textart.com`. That'll tell you where your request is stopping. `netstat -r` will show you your routes and can help you recognize where you should debug.

Comment: When I use netstat -r it does not show me the destination of textfiles.
This is actually a devops quiz I am trying to solve and having hard time with it

Comment: `netstat -r` shows the route not the destination of textfiles. Can you update your question with the output of `ping -c4 textart.com`?